# Gradle Get Transitive Dependency Version Programmatically

Tags: java, gradle

Is there a way to get the version of a transitive dependency programmatically from within the `build.gradle` file?

I have two dependencies which import their own (different) version of the same dependency. I want to *always* use the version that one of the dependencies uses, no matter what version it is using. If possible, I'd like to avoid having to import the dependency myself to start managing it.

```
myProject
  my-dependency-1:module:1.0.0
    group:module:2.0.0
  my-dependency-2:module:1.0.0
    group:module:3.0.0
```

In the above example, I want to make sure that group:module:2.0.0 is always used. Essentially, I want to build a constraint at build time programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude transitive dependencies from being imported:

```
implementation "my-dependency-1:module:1.0.0"
implementation ("my-dependency-2:module:1.0.0") {
  exclude group: "group", module: "module"
}
```

While the transitive dependency would be imported with `my-dependency-1`, it would be excluded from `my-dependency-2`.

Comment: my-dependency-2 is coming from the spring bom and you can't exclude from a platform in gradle AFAIK

Comment: I'd suggest to give it a try. Not sure it's exactly comparable, but Spring Boot has an [example to exclude transitive dependencies](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.10/reference/html/howto.html#howto.webserver.use-another) in their docs. While it's for Maven, we do exactly the same with Gradle.